# Resolve "x2golistsessions: command not found" Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: x2go

I'm attempting to get x2go running on a 14.04.5 LTS server.

When attempting to get connected, I get the message:
`**Connection failed.** bash: x2golistsessions: command not found`
on the client.

After doing some research, I found the suggestion to run on the server:
`apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession xfce4`

I get the result:
`E: Unable to locate package x2goserver`
`E: Unable to locate package x2goserver-xsession`

So far I haven't been able to get further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

I was confused by the fact that some, but not all, of x2go is in the Ubuntu repos. To get everything necessary, you need to add a PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
sudo apt-get install x2gomatebindings # if you use MATE/mubuntu
sudo apt-get install x2golxdebindings # if you use LXDE/lubuntu
```

For the client side:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goclient
```

Hope this helps!

- Hugh

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when trying to make the `x2go` client work in `Windows 10` against a `WSL2 Ubuntu`.

> **Connection failed.** bash: x2golistsessions: command not found on the client

After installing and enabling the `x2goserver` and the `sshd` server in `WSL2 Ubuntu`, what worked for me was to create a new user:

```
useradd -m -G adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,input,netdev,x2gouser,x2goprint -s /bin/bash newuser
```

After this, I setup the `x2go` client to use the new user credentials and the issue dissapeared. I hope this helps someone.